# React previous state not passing in useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

Hey I am trying to use fancypancy react state management and I am so close to getting it to work, but for some reason I can't get my previous state to pass.

```js
const [personalState, setPersonalState] = useState<PersonalState>({
    departments: new Map<string, Person[]>(),
    filteredDepartments: new Map<string, Person[]>(),
    order: "descend",
    headings: [
      { name: "Pic", width: "10%", order: "descend" },
      { name: "Name", width: "10%", order: "descend" },
      { name: "phone", width: "20%", order: "descend" },
      { name: "email", width: "20%", order: "descend" },
      { name: "Date of birth", width: "10%", order: "descend" }
    ],
    handleSort: (name: string) => handleSort(name),
    handleSearchChange: (e: any) => handleSearchChange(e)
  });

// this is only for initalization of state
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Launching use-effect')
    api.getPersons().then((results: any) => {
      const noduplicates = api.filterDuplicateKeysPersons(results.data.Results);
      const personsInDepartments = api.addPersonsToDepartments(noduplicates);
      setPersonalState({
        ...personalState,
        departments: personsInDepartments,
        filteredDepartments: personsInDepartments,
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

So this is part of the code. As you can see I have functions inside my state. When I first load the website, I have both of the maps nicely and can see data. Now When I trigger the function likes this:

```js
const Search = () => {
  const context = useContext();

  return (
    <div className="searchbox">
      <div className="input-group">
          <div className="input-group-prepend">
            <span className="input-group-text" id="">
              Search
            </span>
          </div>
          <input
          className="form-control mr-sm-2"
          type="search"
          placeholder="name"
          aria-label="Search"
          onChange={context.personalState.handleSearchChange}
        />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

then the departments and filtereddepartments go to 0, basically reset. So the data is not sent to the function.

EDIT: As per request adding more context to the problem

```js
// handles search box, filters each person list and creates a new map and puts it under filtered departments
  const handleSearchChange = (event: any) => {
    const filter = event.target.value;
    const newMap = new Map<string, Person[]>();

    function searchUsers() {
      for (const [key, value] of personalState.departments.entries()) {
        const filteredList = value.filter(person => {
          let values = person.Eesnimi.toLowerCase() + " " + person.Perekonnanimi.toLowerCase();
          if (values.indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            return person;
          }
          return values;
        });
        newMap.set(key, filteredList);
      }
    }

    searchUsers();    
    setPersonalState(developerState => {return {...developerState, filteredDepartments: newMap} });
  };
```

NB! I am trying to use this clever idea.
https://gist.github.com/JLarky/5a1642abd8741f2683a817f36dd48e78

These are the values im accessing.

```js
const returnValue = React.useMemo(() => ({
    personalState: personalState, 
    setPersonalState: setPersonalState
  }), [personalState, setPersonalState]);
  return returnValue;
```

EDIT 2: Ive gotten some advancement

I changed the setstate inside the handleSearchChange function

```js
setPersonalState(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        filteredDepartments: searchUsers(prevState)
      }      
    });
```

Now in the searchUsers method above I get the data, but it doesn't update the UI. So all of the time the newMap returns all of the data back, which is weird. I also had an extra return in searchUsers that returned all of the data. After removing that it works.

I guess a little bit of help from the other commentator and my own debugging helped solve this problem for now.

Comment: It's a little bit weird to pass the function as a part of state I guess...
You aren't going to change them, are you? If no, so it's better to exclude handleSort and handleSearchChange from the state and declare them outside. 
Btw share the body of those function, what are they do with the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setPersonalState(prevState => {
    ...prevState,
    departments: personsInDepartments,
    filteredDepartments: personsInDepartments,
  })
```

you need to use a callback to get the previous state

Comment: you mean add useCallBack somewhere inside useState?

Comment: no instead of directly spreading the personalState inside the setState, use an arrow function(callback) with the previous state as an argument. That's how you get the previous state in useState. You have done it yourself in the handleSearch function

Comment: hmm I cant seem to do it like that, i get syntax errors, it thinks prevState is any

Comment: can you try initialising everything in the useEffect itself?

Comment: I added all the fields to useeffect. Then I tried to use setPersonalState in the handlesearchchange, like you said, but it gives an error, I can only access it like so ``` setPersonalState(prevState => {return{...prevState,blaah, blaah}})``` Sorry I cant edit it nicely in the comments

Comment: Ok i got it somewhat working, I'll edit my main post on how far ive gotten now.